# how to subtract values in arrays using javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, arrays

I have 3 arrays of same length. I'd like to subtract the values in the first two arrays,without clicking a button, and if the answer is negative, i get the index of that array number, and display a hidden input field(in html) from the 3rd array, whose array index corresponds to the array index of the negative number.

For example:

```
//assuming this is the first array
array('10','2','3','4','5');
//and assuming this is the second array
array('9','1','4','3','7');
```

i'd like to subtract the values of the second from the first array, such that i have results, for example:

```
array('1','1','-1','1','-2');
```

the above results determines which input fields(from the 3rd array) are to be displayed. For example the input fields to be displayed are those whose array indexes are 2 and 4

here's my code for the 3rd array of input fields:

```
<?php while($roww = mysql_fetch_array($result)) { ?>
     <input type='text' name="reason[]" class="explanation">
<?php } ?>
```

is there any way i can make the above possible?

So far, this what i've tried, though i haven't applied arrays..just a slight update on a sample i found on the internet...

```
<html>
      <head>
            <script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
            <script>
                    $(document).ready(function(){
                     $(".explanation").hide();
                      var input1_ = document.getElementById('num1');
                      var input_ = document.getElementById('num2');
                      function sub(){
                            var answer = (parseInt(input1_.value) - parseInt(input2_.value));
                            if(answer < 0){
                                  $(".explanation").show();
                            }else $(".explanation").hide();
                       }
                       document.getElementById('num1').onkeyup = function () {
                            sub();
                    };
                      document.getElementById('num2').onkeyup = function () {
                            sub();
                   };
            });
</script>

</head>
<body>
     <input type='number'  id='num1' value="0">
     <input type='number'   id='num2' value="0">
     <input type='text' class='explanation' value="0">
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Yes, it is possible. What have you tried?

Comment: i've updated the question, to show what i've done so far..

Answer (score 2):

```
 var a = Array('10','2','3','4','5'); 
 var b = Array('9','1','4','3','7'); 
 var c = a.map(function(v,i) { return (v - b[i]); });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a loop:

```
var result = [];
for (let i=0; i<arr1.length; i++) {
    result[i] = arr1[i]-arr2[i];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

> creates a new array with the results of calling a provided function on every element in this array.

The snippet:

```js
var firstArr = ['10','2','3','4','5'];
var secondArr = ['9','1','4','3','7'];

//
// for each element in the first array
//
var result = firstArr.map(function(val, index) {
  
  // convert the current array value to number
  // subtract the value contained in the second array
  // and return the value
  return +val - +secondArr[index];
});


console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

As long as your arrays are the same length, this should work..

```
function subtrArrays(arr1[], arr2[])
{
    var final = [];
    for(var i = 0; i < arr1.length(); i++)
    {
        final[i] = arr1[i] - arr2[i];
    }
    return final;
}
```

Use:

```
var myArray = subtrArrays(array('10','2','3','4','5'),array('9','1','4','3','7'));
```

Answer (score 0):

This is one of those cases which seems like `Array.prototype.map()` is the best fit but in fact it is not. If you consider the job as a whole `Array.prototype.forEach()` seems better since the return value of `Array.prototype.map()` is going to be useless for us. It's best to finalize the job in an iterating function which doesn't return anything.

```js
var a = ['10','2','3','4','5'],
    b = ['9','1','4','3','7'],
 divs = [div1,div2,div3,div4,div5];
a.forEach((e,i) => e-b[i] < 0 && (divs[i].className = divs[i].className.replace(/\s*hidden\s*/,"")));
```

```css
.hidden {display:none}
```

```html
<div id="div1" class="hidden">div1 text</div>
<div id="div2" class="hidden">div2 text</div>
<div id="div3" class="hidden">div3 text</div>
<div id="div4" class="hidden">div4 text</div>
<div id="div5" class="hidden">div5 text</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You may decide to use forEach method . The forEach method is a method that is used to define the behavior of every element in an array. Let’s say subtract one from each element in the given array

```
   let newArr=[ ]
   const  array=  [ '10','2','3','4','5']
  array.forEach(element =>{
   newArr.push(element-1)
   })
  Console.log(newArr)
```